# How to send SDP over RTP

Tags: rtp, sdp

I've developed an app which sends RTP packets to a local ip client. So the client has to listen on the specified port (rtp://:@portnumber, on VLC) to play the streamed data. Right now i'm going to develop the code needed to create the SDP file needed to start streaming.

My doubt is, how to send this file to the client? At the beginning of the RTP stream? 
Really n00b at this point. Any help will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

VLC specifically supports `RTSP`, `HTTP`, `SAP` protocols for establishing session and communication. And of course the local file system (`file://`)

so basically you can call vlc in some manner like this (I cannot test it but should be like this):

```
vlc file://path/to/sdp-file
```

or

```
vlc rtsp://server-path:port/sdpfile.sdp
```

and so on

Aside from storing the SDP file in the local system, perhaps HTTP would be easiest if you have up and running http server on your server machine.